# React Native - PhaseScriptExecution Error

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an APP in React Native and I'm trying to run it in the IOS simulator. I've already tried in Android and the project run without problem, but when I try to run it on XCode Simulator trows the following error:

```
    line 3: ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code


error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening IDRUS_RSR.xcworkspace

* BUILD FAILED *


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/juanshallcrass/Documents/IDRUS/idrus-rsr/ios/build/IDRUS_RSR/Build/Intermediates.noindex/IDRUS_RSR.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IDRUS_RSR.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
(1 failure)
```

I've already tried changing the **Bundle react Native code and images**, to: `../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` but nothing changed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your project does not have the right permissions, try reinstalling the `node_modules` with your current user

The file `../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` is currently throwing a Permission denied Exception

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the permissions for all the project, but after that it worked.

Comment: @OscarSaro how did you change the permissions?

Comment: Even I am interested in knowing what you did because I am getting the same issue and it's annoying AF. Previously I had to add the command "unset npm_config_prefix" on top of the file find-node.sh inside node_modules/react-native/scripts . But now that is not working anymore.